# Mongo zoned sharding with a single value

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have a database with around 50 collections, and 70 million records. All records belong to specific customers and have a `customerId` property. Currently all clients are in the USA. However, we're in the process of adding EU clients and would like to host their data in an EU datacenter.

Since all records have a `customerId` (which is a string) and virtually all of our queries also specify this `customerId` this makes it a good choice for a shard key for us - we're only going to have one shard per zone, and we'd like all of a customers data to be in that one shard.

My question is, given that the `customerId`'s are strings, how do we specify a `minimum` and `maximum` for the `sh.updateZoneKeyRange()` function? Obiously `minimum` will be the `customerId` (e.g., "customer-somename") but how do we specify a `maximum` of `"customer-somename" + 1`? The issue here is that `maximum` is exclusive, so it can't be the same as `minimum`

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: I rephrased the question and asked on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719381/find-a-string-which-will-always-be-sorted-next-to-a-given-string-regardless-of/55719431#55719431

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `customerId` does not have any obvious mapping to location, it would be best to add a `location` field and create a compound shard key. The `location` field should be a prefix of the shard key, otherwise you will have an administrative headache trying to maintain zones for small ranges of `customerID` values (which could end up as granular as a single customer).

With a compound shard key of  `{location: 1, customerId:1}` your zone ranges would be straightforward to define.

For example:

```
sh.updateZoneKeyRange(
  "mydb.mycollection",
  { "location" : "US", "customerId" : MinKey },
  { "location" : "US", "customerId" : MaxKey },
  "US"
)
```

The MongoDB manual includes a similar example in [Segmenting Data by Location](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/) and this is the same approach used for [MongoDB Atlas' Global Clusters feature](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/global-cluster-sharding/). Both of these examples suggest two-character country codes ([ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)) for the `location` field, but you could choose any values which provide suitable granualarity for your future use cases. For example, [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) would provide for countries and subdivisions (administrative regions like state or province).

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can also [change a document's shard key value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#change-a-document-s-shard-key-value) if you need to move existing user data between zones. You presumably would never want to change your `customerId` values, but could update a `location` field.